how to make it clean to feed a React template from a local text heavy .json file?
I'm doing an SPA right now and the all thing works well so far. To get different text content and pictures according the view, based on the url path, i pull the data from a .json file, local to the SPA, mean by that i don't call any API to get data from.
Here's the structure of that component/layout where i do this templating.
Legal is made of/import HeaderLegal + contentLegal
I call the data into Legal and pass them as props to the 2 other components.
Here's the code:
// data.json
{  "legals": [
    {
      "id": "pp",
      "title": "Privacy policy",
      "update": "last update: 10/05/2024",
      "section1Ttitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
      "section1Text1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
      "section1List": [
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
      ],
      "section2Ttitle": "Information you choose to give us",
      "section2Text1": "When you use hiko, here are the types of information you chose to give us:",
      "section2List": [
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
      ]
    }
}

// Legal component
import HeaderLegal from "../layouts/HeaderLegal";
import ContentLegal from "../layouts/ContentLegal";

const Legal = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const dataLegal = data.legals.find((legal) => legal.id === id);
  return (
    <div>
      <NavLegals />
      <HeaderLegal title={dataLegal.title} text={dataLegal.update} />
      <ContentLegal
        section_1_title={dataLegal.section1Ttitle}
        section_1_text_1={dataLegal.section1Text1}
        section_1_text_2={dataLegal.section1Text2}
        section_1_list={dataLegal.section1List}
        section_2_title={dataLegal.section2Ttitle}
        section_2_text_1={dataLegal.section2Text1}
        section_2_text_2={dataLegal.section2Text2}
        section_2_list={dataLegal.section2List}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

///
// ContentLegal component (that receives the data as props from Legal)
const ContentLegal = ({
  section_1_title,
  section_1_text_1,
  section_1_text_2,
  section_1_list,
  section_2_title,
  section_2_text_1,
  section_2_text_2,
  section_2_list,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <h2>{section_1_title}</h2>
        <p>{section_1_text_1}</p>
        <ul>
          {section_1_list &&
            section_1_list.map((element, index) => {
              return <li key={index}>{element}</li>;
            })}
        </ul>
        <p>{section_1_text_2}</p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>{section_2_title}</h2>
        <p>{section_2_text_1}</p>
        <ul>
          {section_2_list &&
            section_2_list.map((element, index) => {
              return <li key={index}>{element}</li>;
            })}
        </ul>
        <p>{section_2_text_2}</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

It works but as you can see the list of props passed to ContentLegal is long and will increase using this approach and i think i can do better maybe having each section texts from legals array from data.json as object and looping through, but don't see how to implement such thing nor see another alternative. It's kind of dirty like it is right now. Could be definitely better.
Any help and suggestion are welcome.

If you don't mind adding styling context to your json, you could make use of Object.entries.
The idea would be that you could pass the object to the ContentLegal component and iterate the entries to render them out using their styling content:
// data.json
{  "legals": [
{
  "id": "pp",
  "title": "Privacy policy",
  "update": "last update: 10/05/2024",
  "section": {
      "content": [
          {
              "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
              "style": "h2"
          },
          {
              "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
              "style": "p"
          },
          {
              "content": [
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
              ],
              "style": "ul"
          }
      ],
      "style": "section"
  },
  //repeat above for more sections
}

}
// Legal component
import HeaderLegal from "../layouts/HeaderLegal";
import ContentLegal from "../layouts/ContentLegal";

const Legal = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const dataLegal = data.legals.find((legal) => legal.id === id);
  return (
    <div>
      <NavLegals />
      <HeaderLegal title={dataLegal.title} text={dataLegal.update} />
      <ContentLegal data={dataLegal} />
    </div>
  );
};

/// // ContentLegal component (that receives the data as props from Legal)
const ContentLegal = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
          if(key == "section"){
              return `
                         <${value.style}>
                             ${value.content.map((c) => {
                                 if(Array.isArray(c.content)){
                                     return `<${c.style}>
                                         ${c.content.map(l => "<li>" + l + "</li>").join("")}
                                     </${c.style}>`
                                 }
                                 return `<${c.style}>${c.content}</${c.style}>`
                             })}
                         </${value.style}>
              `
          }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

This will give you the flexibility of being able to add any number of elements in a section, but it does mean you will need to restructure your data.json.
Note: This is untested as I can't reproduce without a proper react app, but is indicative of the approach you can take. The exact syntax and implementation may vary to get it working. Here is a JSFiddle with a vanilla JS implementation.
